# One of my questions was deleted, is it possible to recover it?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

The question was about software and network security books, and someone gave me a jolly list of very good books. I asked it before summer 2013, so not so long ago. Any possibility to retrieve the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Click on your 'questions' tab; at the bottom is a link of "[deleted recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2300843)" where you can see your recently deleted questions listed; this only works for questions deleted in the past 60 days.

It looks like your question was undeleted and locked for you for a short time:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224617/books-about-software-security-exploitation-techniques-and-ways-to-prevent-them

Comment: Tried that, I get "No deleted recent questions". I didn't delete the question myself, by the way, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @Metaliinuxite Who deleted it doesn't make any difference as far as I'm aware. It was deleted on April 26th, so I doubt it's still considered a "recently deleted question." [Here's the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224617/software-security), though. You should still be able to view it.

Comment: "deleted recent questions" only shows posts that were made in the last 60 days. On the upside, question authors can now always see their deleted questions and the answers on them provided they have a direct link.

Comment: @AnnaLear: indeed, I was taking the OPs word for it being deleted 'not so long ago'.